# Difference between stdcall and winapi directives?

Tags: delphi, x86-64, calling-convention

According to the online help:
`ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe7/rad/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements.html#Directives`

> 6. winapi is the same as stdcall for Delphi for Win32; 64-bit is different

I always thought that Win64 has only one calling convention. So how can `stdcall` and `winapi` have different meanings on x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 64-bit is different.

That's badly written, and who knows what the author meant.

> I always thought that Win64 has only one calling convention.

You are correct. There really is only one calling convention on x64 Windows. So these directives are essentially ignored on x64.

On x86, `winapi` and `stdcall` happen mean the same thing. But there are other distinct calling conventions on x86 such as `cdecl` and `register`.

Comment: And the `pascal` convention equals to? and you forgot `safecall`

Comment: `pascal` is from 16 bit. And `safecall` isn't really a calling convention. It's `stdcall` with exception/hresult arg re-writing. But let's concentrate on winapi on x64.

Comment: Does that mean that `safecall` works different on x64 than it does on x86?

Comment: No. It works exactly the same. It's not really a distinct calling convention as such.  It is `stdcall`, with parameter re-writing and exception/HRESULT mapping. Semantically the same on x86 and x64.

Comment: If `safecall` is **exactly** the same as `stdcall` on x64, that the `hresult` mapping et al has been removed in x64.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that safecall is the same on x86 as on x64. I'm drawing a distinction between the binary calling convention and the parameter re-writing and exception/HRESULT mapping. In the same sense that methods have a hidden implicit Self parameter that appears before others. They are still register or stdcall or whatever at binary level, but the compiler re-writes the args. safecall is simply a compiler implemented convenience. Clearly safecall and stdcall are not identical.

Comment: This is not strictly true anymore.  For SIMD-heavy functions, the `_vectorcall` convention was recently introduced for x64.  It enables passing vector arguments in the [X/Y]MM or MMX registers.  This is primarily for chainable math functions, naturally, where it saves bouncing vector data to and from the stack. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/12/introducing-vector-calling-convention.aspx  I don't think Delphi supports this calling convention yet, but I expect it will need to in the near future. It's also more of an extension to x64 _fastcall rather than a totally new convention.

Comment: @J... I think you might be disappointed if you hope Emba will add support for this soon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed.  Nevertheless, it does exist and, until it *is* supported, Delphi will not be able to import _vectorcall functions from cpp libraries *because* they use a different calling convention (ie: there is not only one, which is the main point).

Comment: @J... Is it a platform supported calling convention? Anyone can implement their own calling convention.

Comment: Not sure what would make it "platform supported"... microsoft supports it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn375768.aspx  Clang supports it : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#vectorcall-vectorcall-vectorcall  The Intel C++ compiler intends to support it in a future release (see bottom of  https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/Vectorcall_regcall_Demystified.pdf).  Not sure about GCC...

Comment: @J... perhaps someone should tell the msdn folks